# How do I search about this problem(Macro vs Inline function at scope)

Tags: c++, scope, macros, inline

I have some questions about scope.

I think macro acts like copy and paste, and inline function is similar to this but not same.

But, i don't know why this code acts different against my mind.

I dont know what keyword to search, please announce me just some keyword to search.

Thank you for reading.

```
'''
inline int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int num1;

    num1 = add(10, 20);

    printf("%d\n", num1);

    return 0;
} // is same as below
'''
int main()
{
    int num1;

    num1 = int add(int a=10, int b=20)
    {
        return a + b;
    };

    printf("%d\n", num1);

    return 0;
}
'''
#define xtest() cout<<x<<endl

int x=0;

inline void test(){
    cout<<x<<endl;
}

int main(void){
    int x=10;
    test();
    cout<<x<<endl;
    xtest();
    {
        int x = 20;
        test();
        cout<<x<<endl;
        xtest();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I understand `xtest()` and `{cout << x << endl}` acts as same and result is correct, but why the `test()` acts different?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand correctly your probleme, but it's surely a probleme with the scope of the variable 'x'. the test method will write the global variable 'x', while, if you expand your test method in the main function it will write the block local variable'x'

Comment: @Gojita Yes. So, my idea is test() function also print out local variable x, like 10, 20 not 0. Because test() function is defined as inline, so test()'s scope is in local like main, or main's {}. Sorry for bad english, Do I say right?

Comment: `inline` is a rather misleading name. These days it only means that function body can be present in several translation units without upsetting the linker. It does not mean that function scope is changed to the scope of where it is being invoked. So function scope is still global. Your code wouldn't even compile without global `x`.

Comment: an inline function remain a function and act as it. the inline, just say that the compiler, for performance reason, may expand the function code inplace. But scope still remain.

Comment: `inline` is just a hint for the compiler to optimize the function call. It does not change what the function will do or how what scope it is in. It's still a free function, and the only `x` that `test` can see is the global variable.

Comment: @VTT Oh, thank you. Then, You mean that Past time, inline function was really inserted in code? or just 'inline' is presentation, not mechanism?

Comment: @super Thank you. Then inline function can be interpreted differently in many ways for many compilers, or they exist standard of inline? Like there are ways of optimizing code using calling convention

Comment: @Gojita I understand what you mean. Really thank you hhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions marked as `inline` differ from non-`inline` functions in one way only: they can be defined in multiple translation units (= source files) without causing a One Definition Rule violation (= linker error). That's **all**. In all other respects, they behave just like any other function. They are in no way similar to macros.

Comment: Sorry for asking you again because of my bad reading, What does it mean 'they can be defined in multiple translation units (= source files) without causing a One Definition Rule violation (= linker error). '

Comment: @YJS What it means it practice: you can define an `inline` function in a header file and `#include` that header file in more than one `.cpp` file, without the linker complaining about multiple definitions (which it would complain about if you didn't mark the function as `inline`).